# Как передать имя bat файла в самого себя?

Tags: bat

Есть файл с имеем test.bat

Внутри я хочу создать переменную с именем test (без расширения)

```
set filename=*****
echo %filename%
```

Желаемый вывод

```
test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set filename=%~n0
```

Из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for):
`%~nI`  Expands `%I` to a file name only.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! 
Осуждаю себя за нечтение документации)))